# Theory mainly concerned with $\lambda$-calculus?

Tags: soft-question, lo.logic, lambda-calculus, automata-theory

Automata theory is mainly concerned with Turing machines and all its relatives-in-spirit. $\lambda$-calculus is rather rarely mentioned in textbooks on automata theory.

What's the common name of the theory mainly concerned with $\lambda$-calculus and its relatives? (I think, "mathematical logic", "computability theory", "programming language theory" and "recursion theory" are too general, compared to "automata theory". But there should be an "$\lambda$-theory", shouldn't it?)

Comment: What's wrong with just calling it "lambda calculus"?

Comment: Because it's too specific: I think of "lambda calculus and its relatives". And "lambda" is just an artificial word, other than "automata", "computability", and so on.

Comment: Maybe one could call it "function theory" if this name wasn't already in use.

Comment: Anything wrong with "functional programming" besides the fact that it's a computer science term?

Comment: You name it: it's a computer science term. (Don't want to be niggling, but I think the subject deserves a genuine mathematical name.)

Comment: That would never stick unless there's another good reason. Besides, the schism between cs and math is very recent, I would contend that "functional programming" is actually a math term, historically speaking. More importantly, it would be wrong to use a term different than those who use it most, namely theoretical computer scientists, who are very competent mathematicians by the way.

Comment: OK, I surrender. Your last remark has convinced me. But it remains an after-taste: no other (mathematical) theory - as far as I can see it - is named after a practice (it's "proof theory" not "proofing"). 

Comment: To correct myself: there's a mathematical subject called "graph drawing"! So you have won.

Comment: "functional programming" is actually a math term: I've made this assertion into a question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11916/is-functional-programming-a-branch-of-mathematics

Comment: Sadly, the term "theoretical computer science" has been hijacked by the cadre who thinks its only concern is the subrecursive hierarchy ("complexity theory").  Those who work on the CS aspects of semantics and symbolic logic have pretty much abandoned the words "theory" and "theoretical".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

["combinatory logic"](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-combinatory/)

Comment: I should have known this, since I'm a long-time fan of Raymond Smullyan. How could I have overseen this! Thanks. (To say the least: it's an established name.)

Comment: No problem.  I've been using lambda calculus in various forms for twelve years now and it wasn't until recently that I felt I really understood the connection to combinators.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of one that seems sufficiently general.  The theory's at an intersection:

1. It (in its untyped guise) is one of the four most important Turing-complete computation systems;
2. It is algebraically natural, connected fundamentally to Cartesian-closed categories (though with horrid baggage around $\alpha$-equivalence);
3. It is a foundational theory, possibly the theory that best captures the notion of schematic function; and
4. It plays an important role in philosophical logic, due to its link to natural deduction, which is among the few treatments of formal logic that is relevant to the actuality of how we reason.

Maybe a name formed out of keywords from several of these domains would give a suitable term?  How about *Cartesian function-calculus*?

**Edited**

Answer (score 6):

In recent years almost anything I have read about lambda calculus has been about typed lambda calculus. Broadly speaking, I think computer scientists would say that these papers were part of the field known as [Type Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory).

If that doesn't quite fit what you want I'd suggest reading the [PLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_theory) article on Wikipedia.

For example, there is a family of lambda calculi that can be arranged in what is known as the [lambda cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_cube). The wikipedia article starts "In mathematical logic and type theory..."

Comment: Should qualify: *constructive* type theory.

Answer (score 2):

Untyped Lambda Calculus is part of the Recursion Theory, I would say. Typed Lambda Calculus is Type Theory, and is connected with constructive mathematics.

The Lambda-Calculus is a concept that can be applied to many parts of mathematics, so there are few books especially about Lambda-Calculus (Imho lambda calculus : logic = measure theory : analysis, sort of). And the ones I know (i.e. Barendregt, etc.) are just referring to it as "Lambda Calculus".

Answer (score 0):

The lambda calculus is considered one of the fundamental topics in Theoretical Computer Science. You can study it from many points of view:

1. If you study its denotational semantics, then you use algebra and category theory.
2. If you study its operational semantics, then you mainly use rewriting theory.
3. If you study logic, then you will be interested in its type system. You may also be interested in the related system of combinatory logic.
4. If you are a functional programmer, then you are using lambda calculus as a Turing-complete formalism.
5. If you study the foundations of mathematics, then the lambda calculus is related to many foundational systems: Illative combinatory logic, Map Theory, Type Theory, ...

However the term "lambda-theory" is already reserved for a very specific concept: a lambda-theory is a congruence on the set of lambda-terms that contains alpha-beta conversion.